# Is is problematic to set same baseline for several dummy variables?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to do research on the effect of `job type`, `working day` and `job position` on `income`.
The model is something like below. I'm using OLS.

`Income ~ Gender + Age + Job type + Working day + Job position`

Here, `Job type`, `Working day`, `Job position` are dummy variables each coded as

- `Job type(0=Unemployed, 1=Service, 2=Salesman)`
- `Working day(0=Unemployed, 1=5 days a week, 2=6days a week, 3=7days a week)`
- `Job position(0=Unemployed, 1=Temporary, 2=Permanent)`

Here, as you can see, dummy variables are all having same baseline `0=Unemployed`.

I am curious that if this can be a problem since information that baseline for all dummy variables containing is same. Can this be a problem?

Comment: These are not dummy variables. See this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) page for an explanation. Also, check this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/267131/109647) to have a better idea about how to include categorical predictors to your model, especially the part following "*(The remark below might be redundant for you, but I add it anyway)*"